# TableItem does not display a long String Value

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, tableviewer, eclipse-kepler

Eclipse TableItem does not display a long String value.
When I open up the RCP, the TableItem is only displaying only ~260 characters per column.

[image: Character Column Limit]
I am using Windows 7 (64bit), Eclipse Kepler (64bit), Java 1.7.0_25 (64bit)

Here is the source code:

```
public class RecordTableViewerPart {

private TableViewer tableViewer;
private int numberOfColumns = 2;

@PostConstruct
public void createComposite(Composite parent) {
    parent.setLayout(new GridLayout());

    // Define the TableViewer
    TableViewer tableViewer = new TableViewer(parent, SWT.VIRTUAL | SWT.NONE | SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);

    // Create the columns
    for(int i=0; i < numberOfColumns; i++) {
        TableViewerColumn tableViewerColumn = new TableViewerColumn(tableViewer, SWT.NONE);
        tableViewerColumn.getColumn().setWidth(5000);
        tableViewerColumn.getColumn().setText("Column: " + i);
    }


    // Create the sample data
    for(int i=0; i < numberOfColumns; i++) {
        TableItem tableItem = new TableItem(tableViewer.getTable(), SWT.NONE);
        tableItem.setText(i, i + ":" + createLongString());
    }

    final Table table = tableViewer.getTable();
    table.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH));
    table.setHeaderVisible(true);
    table.setLinesVisible(true);
}

private String createLongString() {
    String numbers = new String("0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012" +
                                "9012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901" + 
                                "2345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234" + 
                                "5678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567" +
                                "8901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890" +
                                "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123" +
                                "4567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456" + 
                                "7890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789" + 
                                "0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012" + 
                                "3456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345" +
                                "6789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678" + 
                                "9012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901" +
                                "2345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234" + 
                                "5678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567" +
                                "8901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890" +
                                "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123" +
                                "4567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456" + 
                                "7890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789" + 
                                "0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012" + 
                                "3456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345" +
                                "6789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678" + 
                                "9012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901" +
                                "2345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234" +
                                "5678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567" +
                                "8901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890" +
                                "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123" +
                                "4567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456" + 
                                "7890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789" +
                                "0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012" +
                                "3456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345" +
                                "6789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678" +
                                "9012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901" +
                                "2345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234" +
                                "0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012" +
                                "9012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901" + 
                                "2345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234" + 
                                "5678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567" +
                                "8901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890" +
                                "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123" +
                                "4567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456" + 
                                "7890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789" + 
                                "0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012" + 
                                "3456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345" +
                                "6789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678" + 
                                "9012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901" +
                                "2345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234" +
                                "5678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567" +
                                "8901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890" +
                                "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123" +
                                "4567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456" + 
                                "7890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789" +
                                "0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012" +
                                "3456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345" +
                                "9012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901" +
                                "2345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234");
    System.out.println(numbers.length());
    return numbers.toString();
}
```

}

Comment: This might be related to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6621076/1288408) and [this bug entry](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=77711).

Comment: Not sure if you need Nebula for it, but a multiline item could be a reasonable work-around.