# SWT/JFace columns don't show whole content

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface, tablecolumn

I have a JFace TableViewer with some columns. I noticed that my columns only show 259 characters. That is undependet to the column's width. My ColumnLabelProvider returns the full text.

For example the following String is cutted before the "Z". The "Z" and everything after it isn't displayed.
123456789A123456789B123456789C123456789D123456789E123456789F123456789G123456789H123456789I123456789J123456789K123456789L123456789M123456789N123456789O123456789P123456789Q123456789R123456789S123456789T123456789U123456789V123456789W123456789X123456789Y123456789Z

Is there any way to increase the limit number of displayed characters?? Or does anyone know a walk around?

Comment: possible duplicate of [swt table has limitation on text length in a cell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6621076/swt-table-has-limitation-on-text-length-in-a-cell)

Comment: Thanks, that didn't appeared in my web search. So it is a 10 years old bu caused by Windows. :(

Comment: Yeah, afraid there is nothing you can do (except for rendering the cells yourself as explained in the linked question).

Comment: I found a really simple way to get the result I wanted. You simply have to use a StyledCellLabelProvider. My full answer here [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6621076/swt-table-has-limitation-on-text-length-in-a-cell/26717402#26717402)